# "Undefined reference to" error for C function in same file

Tags: c

Just learning how to use pointers in C and am having an error when declaring a function which uses a pointer as a parameter

```
#include <stdio.h>

int a[10];

int strlen(const char *str);

int main(){
    printf("%d", strlen("This works"));
    return 0;
}
int strlen(char *s){
    int n;
    for (n = 0; *s != '\0'; s++)
        n++;
    return n;
}
```

When compiling I receive the following error

```
Undefined reference to 'strlen(char const*)'
```

Comment: Don't use a standard name for your own functions.

Comment: You seem to use a C++ compiler. **Don't**! C++ is a different language.

Comment: note: making your own function with the same name as a library function causes undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

In declaration, you have

```
int strlen(const char *str);
```

However, in definition, it becomes

```
int strlen(char *s){
```

Notice the difference? To make your code work, you have to make definition and declaration same, or you'll get an error, since linker cannot find the definition of `int strlen(const char *str);`

To fix this error, change the declaration to

```
int myStrlen(const char *str);
```

and the definition to

```
int myStrlen(const char *s){
```

And try again.

Since `strlen()` is a C library function, you should not to use this name. Also, I say "**try** again", rather than "it **will** work", because we are not using the same compiler, so I'm not sure whether this will fix your problem on your implementation. If you're using a C++ compiler to compile a this code, you'd better use a C compiler instead, for C and C++ are separate languages.

Comment: That would not give the posted error message, but a redeclaration error for the definition.

Comment: @Olaf Maybe you are using different compilers?

Comment: I use a C compiler. Do you use a C++ compiler with name-mangling?

Comment: Btw: the name is already reserved by the C standard, it must not be used in user-code.